# Jetson TX1 will not boot, how do I completely reinstall Ubuntu on it?

Tags: boot, 16.04, nvidia, reinstall

I upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, which I now regret. After I upgraded, Ubuntu would completely freeze while I was in the GUI. I could still access the terminal though. I tried installing JetPack on my TX1 by setting it into recovery mode, but now it will not even boot. I do see the solid two green lights, but I don't get any HDMI output. I have nothing I need on the TX1, so I want to completely reinstall Ubuntu 14.04. If you need any other information, please ask.
I've already spent a few hour trying and I am new to Linux so if anyone could help, that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem.

Flashing again from JetPack didn't work, but then I noticed something weird during the flashing process (on the Component Manager page, the actions towards "Target - Jetson TX1" are all skipped automatically). There's no error messages so I assumed the flashing completed, however it's not.

I still don't know why this happened because I haven't done anything on my host computer, but after uninstalling JetPack and reinstalling it the process became normal. Anyway, make sure your flashing process is finished.

This might not be very related to the question but remember to run `chmod +x JetPack-${VERSION}.run` to give it exec permission before running JetPack. I always forget this lol.